# importing a certificate to keystore in Tomcat using Powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax, certificate, keystore, keytool

I am trying to import a certificate into a keystore.jks located in my tomcat/conf directory. I've done this many times in the past using command prompt. I normally just cd into the tomcat/conf directory and enter the following line:

“C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe” -import -alias “alias CA-30” -file cert.cer -keystore keystore.jks

However, they've recently blocked us from using command prompt and so I am doing this in Powershell, which I've never used before. This is the error I am getting:

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator

And it is pointing to the first "-" right before "import."

Can someone tell me the proper syntax for this statement in powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `&` at the beginning. Try this:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias "alias CA-30" -file cert.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

PowerShell can run exe but it also evaluates expressions e.g.:

```
C:\PS> 3 + 4
7
C:\PS> "Hello world!"
Hello world!
```

As you can see, when PowerShell sees a string at the beginning of a pipeline, it evaluates the string by writing the string to the host.  In order to get PowerShell to execute the string as the name (or path to) a command, you need to put the call operator `&` in front of it:

```
& "path-with-spaces-has-to-be-quoted.exe"
```

or

```
$cmd = "Get-Date"
& $cmd
```